# Calculate 40 digits of the MRB constant

Tags: summation, number-theory, digits

> [MRB constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MRBConstant.html) is the upper limit point of the following sequence
>
> $$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^k k^{\frac{1}{k}}$$
>
> $MRB=\color{blue}{0.1878596}...$

I tried to calculate first few digits:

```
Sum[(-1)^k k^(1/k), {k, 1, 3 000 000}] // N // AbsoluteTiming
```

> $\lbrace{83.152 , \color{blue}{0.1878}} \color{red}{62} \rbrace $

*I also tried* `NSum` *but* ... *there is a different result*

```
NSum[(-1)^k k^(1/k), {k, 1, Infinity}]
```

> $\color{red}{-0.31214}$

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 1000}, 
NSum[(-1)^k k^(1/k), {k, 1, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 40]]
```

[image]

***How can I calculate 40 digits of the MRB constant?***

Comment: I presume you've seen [this thread by the creator of the constant himself](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/366628).

Comment: @J.M. What an entertaining post! He's really meticulous in keeping notes of his progress...

Comment: Hi. There have been several updates to my MRB constant thread linked above. I think you would enjoy looking at it a second time!

Answer (score 3):

First of all take a look at the thread mentioned in the comments for a sequence with faster convergence.

Using one of the more obvious series (also mentioned in the MathWorld article you linked), the following code produces the MRB constant with 40 digits of accuracy:

```
NSum[(-1)^k (k^(1/k) - 1), {k, 1, ∞}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
  NSumTerms -> 10000
]
```

Comment: You might want to try the setting `Method -> "AlternatingSigns"`, so you don't need a large setting of `NSumTerms`.